# Why is there a white space on the right side of my website?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a website which have a white space on the right side of the page. It makes the page scrollable horizontally. I have added `overflow: hidden` to the css. It works perfectly when the web is opened in Chrome. However, when i tried opening it with safari or on mobile phones, the white spaces came back.

screenshot of the website can be seen here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UryAukJhRS4yTHBPuJ8F_3uqeVcdWrln/view?usp=sharing

my html:

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'web/style.css' %}">
    
    <!-- Add icon library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <title>Eximia Denim Co.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'web:index' %}" id="brand-name">Eximia Denim Co.</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- <a class="brand" style="margin: 0; float: none; text-align:center" href="#">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GyjZFjL.png" width="100px" />
            </a> -->
        
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'web:index' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'web:about' %}">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'web:contact' %}">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="https://shopee.co.id/shop/292750693/">Order</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <section id='highlight-1'>
        </section>

        <a href="https://shopee.co.id/shop/292750693/">
          <img src="{% static 'web/images/promo2020.jpg' %}" id="promo-1">
        </a>

        <section id='cards-1'>
          <div class="row">
            
                <div class="col-md-6" id="card-1">
                  <h1>Unique. Soft.</h1>
                  <img src="{% static 'web/images/soft.jpg' %}"class="center">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6" id="card-2">
                  <h1>Fashionable. Tough.</h1>
                  <img src="{% static 'web/images/hard.jpg' %}" class="center">
                </div>
              
          </div>
        </section>

        <section>
          <img src="{% static 'web/images/new-product-banner.jpg' %}" id="new-product">
        </section>

        <footer class="footer">

          <br>
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/eximia.denim/" class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></a>
          <a href="https://wa.me/628114538300" class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
            © 2020 Copyright
          </div>
    
        </footer>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css :

```
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 70px;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#brand-name {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#highlight-1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("images/highlight-1.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
}

#promo-1 {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#cards-1 {
  width: 100%;
}

#cards-1 #card-1 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f4b41a;
}

#cards-1 #card-1 h1 {
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #143d59;
}

#cards-1 #card-2 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #143d59;
}

#cards-1 #card-2 h1 {
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #f4b41a;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#new-product {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.fa {
  color: white !important;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.fa:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  
}
```

any help would be very appreciated.

Edit:
Fixed the site finally.

Added to my style.css:

```
* {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us the HTML rather than template scripts, so we can reproduce the problem? See how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that has the minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem, so we can help!

Comment: Please make a HTML+CSS snippet.

Comment: @FluffyKitten hi yeah im very confused on how i can do that because this webpage is so dependant on so many images that i store as static files. perhaps you can visit the website here: eximia-denim.herokuapp.com. im sorry im really new at this.

Comment: That's not the way Stack Overflow works :) This is Q&A repository for other users also, so questions must be self contained. When you fix your site, this question is no longer valid so it is not longer useful to other users. If you take a look at the link for creating a [mre] it explains what you need to include and has some tips to get there.

Comment: @FluffyKitten hmm alrightt thank you so much tho!! i have a question tho if you happen to know. why is that the web page shows up differently on chrome and differently on safari/mobile phone? such as like the problems i have above. i dont have the white space on chrome but i have it when i open it on safari or on my phone.

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the code! Every browser has its own way of rendering the page which can result in differences. they can handle certain features slightly differently and not all browsers support all CSS features, or act differently if there is an error somewhere  in the HTML or CSS for example. If you could create an example, that would really help us to be able to help :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Hmm alrighttt! thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `margin: 0 !important;` at `.row`

When i had same problem, I managed to fix it this way.

Hope it could help

*PS
It could happen if you don't put your content in .col inside of .row

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

Remove *margin-left: -15px* and *margin-right: -15px* for your .row class
You can find in #cards-1 section > .row

Comment: Please explain how this will fix the issue in the question. Also it is rare that you should need to override the behaviour of Bootstrap classes, there is usually something else that is affecting the behaviour (often the incorrect use of the classes in the first place) .It should be avoided where possible because it can cause issues down the line, when maintaining the non-standard CSS or when upgrading the Bootstrap version.